# Discord Music Bot don't play music/sound

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-bot

I would like to ask for some help about my bot where after I use
!play  it just joined the voice channel but doesn't play the link I give

here's my code, please tell me what's the problem
https://paste.pythondiscord.com/UGUA

any solution to my problem? I also added the ffmpeg environment variables to PATH

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as a link.  Please also include the debugging steps you used to attempt to fix this problem.